# Micronaut POST not creating DTO class

Tags: java, dto, micronaut, micronaut-data

Following the guidelines of the Micronaut database access toolkit, I have the following classes in order to create a new Uploader entity.

UploaderController

```
@Post
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UploaderCreatedResponse createUploader(@Body CreateUploaderRequest request) throws UploaderNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("request");
    System.out.println(request);
    System.out.println(request.getUploader());

    return new UploaderCreatedResponse(true, uploaderService.createNewUploader(request.getUploader()));

}
```

CreateUploaderRequest

```
package com.digithurst.adminui.controller.requests;

import com.digithurst.adminui.controller.requests.dto.UploaderCreateDTO;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CreateUploaderRequest implements Serializable {
    private UploaderCreateDTO uploader;

    public CreateUploaderRequest() {
    }

    public CreateUploaderRequest(UploaderCreateDTO uploader) {
        this.uploader = uploader;
    }
    public UploaderCreateDTO getUploader() {
        return uploader;
    }
    public void setUploader(UploaderCreateDTO uploader) {
        this.uploader = uploader;
    }
}
```

UploaderCreateDTO

```
package com.digithurst.adminui.controller.requests.dto;

public class UploaderCreateDTO {

    private String api_key;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int retention;

    public UploaderCreateDTO() {
    }

    public UploaderCreateDTO(String api_key, String name, String description, int retention) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.retention = retention;
    }

    public String getApi_key() {
        return api_key;
    }

    public void setApi_key(String api_key) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getRetention() {
        return retention;
    }

    public void setRetention(int retention) {
        this.retention = retention;
    }
}
```

When I issue a POST request to the server with all the parameters the DTO class is not initiated. Am I missing something?

[image]

Output:

com.something.adminui.controller.requests.CreateUploaderRequest@6f485905

null

Comment: Can you update your question and show the complete POST body instead of a screenshot where a crucial part is not shown?

Comment: It is all there. What else do you need?

Comment: I don't see the start and the end of the json body. I think it should be { "uploader" : {...}}

Comment: You were right. Please post as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `CreateUploaderRequest` for the `@Body` method parameter, not the `UploaderCreateDTO`.

So you need to use the properties from `CreateUploaderRequest` in your JSON, otherwise the deserializer won't recognize the fields, and simply use the default constructor.

In this case:

```
{ 
   "uploader" : {
     "api_key": "something",
     ...
   }
}
```